# Linebreak not working for long lines in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

In my list of figures for some long captions, the caption goes beyond the right corner of the page but not for all of them. I tried the solution here: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11021 but didn't work (    \usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref})

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You are probably using something like `\verb!SETTINGS!` or an `\mbox` which cannot be broken. Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Are the line breaks working correctly in the captions themselves?

Comment: @Mico, yes, they work.

Comment: A term such as "didn't work" simply is not helpful. A screenshot isn't particularly helpful either. If you don't tell us more about your document setup -- preferably in the form of a minimum working example that replicates the problem at hand -- it's not likely that anyone will be able to come up with a diagnosis of the problem, let alone a be able to propose a cure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text in typewriter font normally does not linebreak. To get linebreaks, use `\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{some very very very very long caption with typewriter text \texttt{some\_long\_typewriter\_text}}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures


\end{document}
```